# Get Cortana to work in English (UK) for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, language, regional-settings, cortana

I upgraded to Windows 10, and Cortana doesn’t seem to be available based on the Start Menu:

> Cortana isn’t supported in the region and language you’ve selected.

[image: Start Menu screenshot]

but when I click the link, it takes me to this page:

[image: screenshot of help page]

which suggests it should be available in the UK, since I've checked

- my language settings are English (UK),
- I have the English (UK) language pack installed, and
- the speech settings are also set to English (UK).

I think this is everything, right?  It certainly ticks the boxes in the Microsoft help article.

How can I get Cortana up & running?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft states that **Cortana** is **available** in the **UK**.

Even if **region**, **language** and **input** are **set** to **UK**,  users are unable to get Cortana.

This is a **well-known bug** from Microsoft.

---

There's a **workaround** for that **bug**.

- Cortana shows you with **two** options: **Settings** and **Not Interested**.
- When you click settings it will take you to another page only to tell you that  then you cannot enable Cortana as it is "not available in my region".
- However If you click **Not Interested**, you'll be taken to a page to setup Cortana.

> Someone at Microsoft must have changed the Button's text as an Evil joke

Answer (score 1):

It has been established that this is a bug affecting only the `en-GB` users of Windows 10, and it only crops up on the odd occasion on PCs. Microsoft has confirmed it is a bug, and is working on patching it. The only two solutions so far would be to reset your PC or wait for Microsoft to release an update on patch Tuesday, the second Tuesday of each month.

**EDIT**: This is from a Live support tech, but you can also find a comment here:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_cortana/cortana-in-windows-10-disabled-by-company-policy/811b8964-367a-41cc-b7ba-033d0e9dee47

> I spoke with MS support today (since now 10240 is officially supported :) ) and they said this is a known bug in which they're working on.

**EDIT 2**: Reset your PC:

[image: Settings]

Comment: Do you have a link with any more info? I googled and googled and couldn't find anything....

Comment: Could you let us know the source for this information? Also, what do you mean by 'reset' my PC?

Comment: @Stewart_R does that help? Again, Windows 10 is still not finished and Microsoft is patching everything as fast as they can